# Change 'Series' + 'Number' entries in bibliography with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

Following the style guidelines for an article I'm writing, I need to make sure that the title of the book series is followed by a comma, the number within that series, and a period.

E.g.

> Sander, M. (2011). *Marketing-Management — Märkte, Marktforschung und Marktbearbeitung* (2., komplett überarb. Aufl.). UTB, Nr. 8251. Konstanz, München: UVK/Lucius.
>
> Saxer, U. (1999). Der Forschungsgegenstand der Medienwissenschaft. In J.-F. Leonhard / H.-W. Ludwig / D. Schwarze / E. Straßner (Hrsg.), *Medienwissenschaft — Ein Handbuch zur Entwicklung der Medien und Kommunikationsformen* (Bd. 1, Bde. 3, S. 1–14). Handbücher zur Sprach- und Kommunikationswissenschaft, Nr. 15. Berlin, New York: W. de Gruyter.
>
> Schenk, M. (1989). Einführung in die Medienökonomie. In M. Schenk / J. Donnerstag (Hrsg.), *Medienökonomie — Einführung in die Ökonomie der Informations- und Mediensysteme: ein Reader* (S. 3–11). Reihe Medien-Skripten, Nr. 6. München: R. Fischer.

But what I get so far is:

> Sander, M. (2011). *Marketing-Management — Märkte, Marktforschung und Marktbearbeitung* (2., komplett überarb. Aufl.). UTB. Konstanz, München: UVK/Lucius.
>
> Saxer, U. (1999). Der Forschungsgegenstand der Medienwissenschaft. In J.-F. Leonhard / H.-W. Ludwig / D. Schwarze / E. Straßner (Hrsg.). A. Burkhardt / H. Stegen / H. E. Wiegand (**typeredactors**), *Medienwissenschaft — Ein Handbuch zur Entwicklung der Medien und Kommunikationsformen* (Bd. 1, Nr. 15, Bde. 3, S. 1–14). Handbücher zur Sprach- und Kommunikationswissenschaft. Berlin, New York: W. de Gruyter.
>
> Schenk, M. (1989). Einführung in die Medienökonomie. In M. Schenk / J. Donnerstag (Hrsg.), *Medienökonomie — Einführung in die Ökonomie der Informations- und Mediensysteme: ein Reader* (Nr. 6, S. 3–11). Reihe Medien-Skripten. München: R. Fischer.

What command(s) can I include in the preamble of my .tex file that will result in such a bibliography?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,toc=listof]{scrartcl} 
\linespread{1.25}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm, right=2cm, bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[
style=apa,
sorting=nyt,
sortcites=true,
maxbibnames=99,
maxcitenames=2,
backend=biber,
bibliography=totoc,
isbn=false,
doi=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{german}{german-apa}
\DeclareFieldFormat{apacase}{#1}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{ 
   andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},             
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Sander_2011,
  location = {{Konstanz, M{\"u}nchen}},
  edition = {2., komplett {\"u}berarb. Aufl.},
  title = {Marketing-{{Management}} \textemdash{} {{M{\"a}rkte}}, {{Marktforschung}} und {{Marktbearbeitung}}},
  number = {8251},
  series = {UTB},
  publisher = {{UVK/Lucius}},
  author = {Sander, Matthias},
  date = {2011}
}
@incollection{Saxer_1999,
  location = {{Berlin, New York}},
  title = {Der {{Forschungsgegenstand}} der {{Medienwissenschaft}}},
  volume = {1},
  volumes = {3},
  number = {15},
  booktitle = {Medienwissenschaft \textemdash{} {{Ein Handbuch}} zur {{Entwicklung}} der {{Medien}} und {{Kommunikationsformen}}},
  series = {Handb{\"u}cher zur Sprach- und Kommunikationswissenschaft},
  publisher = {{W. de Gruyter}},
  author = {Saxer, Ulrich},
  editor = {Leonhard, Joachim-Felix and Ludwig, Hans-Werner and Schwarze, Dietrich and Stra\ss{}ner, Erich},
  editorb = {Burkhardt, Armin and Steger, Hugo and Wiegand, Herbert Ernst},
  editorbtype = {redactor},
  date = {1999},
  pages = {1--14}
}
@incollection{Schenk_1989,
  location = {{M{\"u}nchen}},
  title = {Einf{\"u}hrung in die {{Medien{\"o}konomie}}},
  timestamp = {2016-08-11T10:23:03Z},
  number = {6},
  booktitle = {Medien{\"o}konomie \textemdash{} {{Einf{\"u}hrung}} in die {{{\"O}konomie}} der {{Informations}}- und {{Mediensysteme}}: ein {{Reader}}},
  series = {Reihe Medien-Skripten},
  publisher = {{R. Fischer}},
  author = {Schenk, Michael},
  editor = {Schenk, Michael and Donnerstag, Joachim},
  date = {1989},
  pages = {3--11}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace}

\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}[0]{\,/\,} 
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}[0]{\,/\,}
\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}[0]{\,/\,} 
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}[0]{\,/\,}
}

\setcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{100}  % allow breaks at numbers

\DeclareFieldFormat{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}

% name sort always last, first
\AtBeginBibliography{%
    \DeclareNameAlias{editor}{last-first}
}

\begin{document}

That's important stuff (\cites{Sander_2011}{Saxer_1999}{Schenk_1989}).

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you unaccepted the answer below and the one to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/324539/35864?

Comment: Excuse me, it was just a mistake. your answer was perfect! I just re-accepted the answer. It was just confused with the check-logo and the pen-logo and thought, i haven't accepted it in the first place...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Before we start the obligatory *if-you-modify-`biblatex-apa`-you-probably-lose-APA-compliance* warning. Since `biblatex-apa` tries to follow APA style to the letter, you probably lose APA compliance if you modify the style. Also modifying the style can be quite a hassle, because `biblatex-apa` goes through great lengths to follow the APA style.)

Apparently in `biblatex-apa` `number` is treated as a supplement to `volume` and `part` in some types. The field is printed in several helper macros, so we need to get rid of it there at first

```
\renewbibmacro*{addinfo}{%
  \ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{edition}\AND%
              \iffieldundef{chapter}\AND%
              \iffieldundef{volumes}\AND%
              \iffieldundef{pages}\AND%
              \(\iffieldundef{volume}\OR\boolean{bbx:volseen}\)}
  {}
  {\printtext{\bibopenparen}%
   \printfield{edition}%
   \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
   \printfield{chapter}%
   \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
   \notbool{bbx:volseen}%
     {\iffieldundef{volume}{}{\global\booltrue{bbx:volseen}}%
      \printfield{volume}%
      \iffieldundef{part}{}{\printfield{part}}}{}%
   \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
   \printfield{volumes}%
   \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
   \printfield{pages}%
   \setunit{}%
   \printtext{\bibcloseparen}%
   \newunit}}

\renewbibmacro*{maintitle+title}{%
  \iffieldsequal{maintitle}{title}
    {\clearfield{maintitle}%
     \clearfield{mainsubtitle}%
     \clearfield{maintitleaddon}}
    {\iffieldundef{maintitle}
      {}
      {\usebibmacro{maintitle}%
       \newunit\newblock
       \iffieldundef{volume}
         {}
         {\setunit{\global\booltrue{bbx:volseen}}%
          \printfield{volume}%
          \printfield{part}%
          \setunit{\adddot\space}}}}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{maintitle+booktitle}{%
  \ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{maintitle}\AND\iffieldundef{booktitle}}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{in}%
     \iffieldundef{maintitle}
      {}
      {\usebibmacro{maintitle}%
       \newunit\newblock
       \iffieldundef{volume}
         {}
         {\setunit{\addspace\global\booltrue{bbx:volseen}}%
          \printfield{volume}%
          \printfield{part}%
          \setunit{\adddot\addspace}}}%
    \usebibmacro{booktitle}}}
```

Then we can define our own macro for `series` and `number` (more or less the one from `standard.bbx`)

```
\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \printfield{series}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \newunit}
```

Then we need to modify the drivers, that is easiest done with the `xpatch` package. We remove explicit `\printfield{nzumber}` and `\printfield{series}`, the latter are replaced by a call to our new macro.

```
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchbibdriver{book}
  {\printfield{series}}
  {\usebibmacro{series+number}}
  {}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{inbook}
  {\printfield{series}}
  {\usebibmacro{series+number}}
  {}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\printfield{series}}
  {\usebibmacro{series+number}}
  {}{}

\xpatchbibdriver{collection}
  {\printfield{number}}
  {}
  {}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{collection}
  {\printfield{series}}
  {\usebibmacro{series+number}}
  {}{}
```

The MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,toc=listof]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
style=apa,
sorting=nyt,
sortcites=true,
maxbibnames=99,
maxcitenames=2,
backend=biber,
bibliography=totoc,
isbn=false,
doi=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}
\DeclareFieldFormat{apacase}{#1}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
   andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},             
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Sander_2011,
  location   = {Konstanz and M{\"u}nchen},
  edition    = {2., komplett {\"u}berarb. Aufl.},
  title      = {Marketing-Management \textemdash{} M{\"a}rkte, Marktforschung und Marktbearbeitung},
  number     = {8251},
  series     = {UTB},
  publisher  = {{UVK/Lucius}},
  author     = {Sander, Matthias},
  date       = {2011},
}
@incollection{Saxer_1999,
  location    = {Berlin and New York},
  title       = {Der Forschungsgegenstand der Medienwissenschaft},
  volume      = {1},
  volumes     = {3},
  number      = {15},
  booktitle   = {Medienwissenschaft \textemdash{} Ein Handbuch zur Entwicklung der Medien und Kommunikationsformen},
  series      = {Handb{\"u}cher zur Sprach- und Kommunikationswissenschaft},
  publisher   = {W. de Gruyter},
  author      = {Saxer, Ulrich},
  editor      = {Leonhard, Joachim-Felix and Ludwig, Hans-Werner and Schwarze, Dietrich and Stra\ss{}ner, Erich},
  editorb     = {Burkhardt, Armin and Steger, Hugo and Wiegand, Herbert Ernst},
  editorbtype = {redactor},
  date        = {1999},
  pages       = {1--14},
}
@incollection{Schenk_1989,
  location  = {M{\"u}nchen},
  title     = {Einf{\"u}hrung in die Medien{\"o}konomie},
  number    = {6},
  booktitle = {Medien{\"o}konomie \textemdash{} Einf{\"u}hrung in die {\"O}konomie der Informations- und Mediensysteme: ein Reader},
  series    = {Reihe Medien-Skripten},
  publisher = {R. Fischer},
  author    = {Schenk, Michael},
  editor    = {Schenk, Michael and Donnerstag, Joachim},
  date      = {1989},
  pages     = {3--11},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace}

\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\,/\,} 
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\,/\,}
\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\,/\,}%
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\,/\,}%
}

\setcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{100}  % allow breaks at numbers

\DeclareFieldFormat{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}

% name sort always last, first
\AtBeginBibliography{%
    \DeclareNameAlias{editor}{family-given}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{addinfo}{%
  \ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{edition}\AND%
              \iffieldundef{chapter}\AND%
              \iffieldundef{volumes}\AND%
              \iffieldundef{pages}\AND%
              \(\iffieldundef{volume}\OR\boolean{bbx:volseen}\)}
  {}
  {\printtext{\bibopenparen}%
   \printfield{edition}%
   \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
   \printfield{chapter}%
   \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
   \notbool{bbx:volseen}%
     {\iffieldundef{volume}{}{\global\booltrue{bbx:volseen}}%
      \printfield{volume}%
      \iffieldundef{part}{}{\printfield{part}}}{}%
   \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
   \printfield{volumes}%
   \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
   \printfield{pages}%
   \setunit{}%
   \printtext{\bibcloseparen}%
   \newunit}}

\renewbibmacro*{maintitle+title}{%
  \iffieldsequal{maintitle}{title}
    {\clearfield{maintitle}%
     \clearfield{mainsubtitle}%
     \clearfield{maintitleaddon}}
    {\iffieldundef{maintitle}
      {}
      {\usebibmacro{maintitle}%
       \newunit\newblock
       \iffieldundef{volume}
         {}
         {\setunit{\global\booltrue{bbx:volseen}}%
          \printfield{volume}%
          \printfield{part}%
          \setunit{\adddot\space}}}}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{maintitle+booktitle}{%
  \ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{maintitle}\AND\iffieldundef{booktitle}}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{in}%
     \iffieldundef{maintitle}
      {}
      {\usebibmacro{maintitle}%
       \newunit\newblock
       \iffieldundef{volume}
         {}
         {\setunit{\addspace\global\booltrue{bbx:volseen}}%
          \printfield{volume}%
          \printfield{part}%
          \setunit{\adddot\addspace}}}%
    \usebibmacro{booktitle}}}

\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \printfield{series}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \newunit}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchbibdriver{book}
  {\printfield{series}}
  {\usebibmacro{series+number}}
  {}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{inbook}
  {\printfield{series}}
  {\usebibmacro{series+number}}
  {}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\printfield{series}}
  {\usebibmacro{series+number}}
  {}{}

\xpatchbibdriver{collection}
  {\printfield{number}}
  {}
  {}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{collection}
  {\printfield{series}}
  {\usebibmacro{series+number}}
  {}{}

\begin{document}
That's important stuff \parencites{Sander_2011}{Saxer_1999}{Schenk_1989}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives

> Sander, M. (2011). Marketing-Management — Märkte, Marktforschung und Marktbearbeitung (2., komplett überarb. Aufl.). UTB, Nr. 8251. Konstanz: UVK/Lucius.
>
> Saxer, U. (1999). Der Forschungsgegenstand der Medienwissenschaft. In J.-F. Leonhard/H.-W. Ludwig/D. Schwarze/E. Straßner (Hrsg.). A. Burkhardt/H. Steger/H. E. Wiegand (typeredactors), Medienwissenschaft — Ein Handbuch zur
>   Entwicklung der Medien und Kommunikationsformen (Bd. 1, Bde. 3, S. 1–14).
>   Handbücher zur Sprach- und Kommunikationswissenschaft, Nr. 15. Berlin: W. de
>   Gruyter.
>
> Schenk, M. (1989). Einführung in die Medienökonomie. In M. Schenk/J. Donnerstag (Hrsg.), Medienökonomie — Einführung in die Ökonomie der Informations- und Mediensysteme: ein Reader (S. 3–11). Reihe Medien-Skripten, Nr. 6. München: R. Fischer.

---

The `redactor`s can be deleted as follows

```
\AtEveryBibitem{
  \iffieldequalstr{editortype}{redactor}
    {\global\clearname{editor}\typeout{delete editor (type: redactor) in \thefield{citekey}}}{}%
  \iffieldequalstr{editoratype}{redactor}
    {\global\clearname{editora}\typeout{delete editora (type: redactor) in \thefield{citekey}}}{}%
  \iffieldequalstr{editorbtype}{redactor}
    {\global\clearname{editorb}\typeout{delete editorb (type: redactor) in \thefield{citekey}}}{}%
  \iffieldequalstr{editorctype}{redactor}
    {\global\clearname{editorc}\typeout{delete editorc (type: redactor) in \thefield{citekey}}}{}%
}
```

Comment: Thats just awesome! Thank you very very much – it worked!

Comment: But can you help me to get rid of these "typeredactors" you see in the example with Saxer (1999). It looks like this apastyle wants to add the series editors after the book editors. But i don't need them here and also in the rest of this bibliography style. Can we define a command that will act like they aren't in the bib entries? That would help me quite a lot! Thank you!

Comment: @Leandro I have added some code that deleted editors with `redactor` type.